# Redux await dispatch and handle errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I use redux-thunk like this in typescript:

```
//store
export const thunkCreateArticle = (articleCreateView: ArticleCreateView):
    ThunkAction<void, ArticleState, BlogClient, Action<string>> => async (dispatch, _, api) => {
        const article = await api.createArticle(articleCreateView);
        dispatch({
            payload: article,
            type: CREATE_ARTICLE,
        });
    };

//component
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, any>): DispatchProps => {
    return {
        addArticle: async (add: v.ArticleCreateView) => {
            dispatch(thunkCreateArticle(add));
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to await `dispatch` in `addArticle` in `mapDispatchToProps` so I can do something AFTER `addArticle` completed and handle errors with try-catch. All solutions I have found for this use a global error handler which is awful IMO. My client is stateful, so I use the extra argument from thunk to 'inject' it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It by assigning the right typings:

```
export type ActionTypes = ....;
export type BlogThunkResult<R> = ThunkAction<R, RootState, BlogClient, ActionTypes>;
export type BlogThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, BlogClient, ActionTypes>;


export const thunkUpdateArticle = (articleId: number, articleUpdateView: ArticleCreateView):
    BlogThunkResult<Promise<void>> => async (dispatch, _, api) => {
    const article = await api.updateArticle(articleId, articleUpdateView);
    dispatch({
        payload: article,
        type: UPDATE_ARTICLE,
    });
};
```

If I use `dispatch` now I get a promise which can be awaited and errors are properly passed down to the caller.